# Any way to override view_mode in twig directly?

Tags: theming

For some reasons, I need to render a content twice, the first one in default view mode, the second one with thumbnail view mode.

In field--paragraph--field-slide--gallery.html.twig I tried to use the following code, however, got a fatal error.

```
{% for item in items %}
  {{ item.content }}
{% endfor %}

{% for item in items %}
  {% set item.content['#view_mode'] = 'thumbnail' %}
  {{ item.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

Any another idea to get the similar output?

Answer (score 1):

The fatal error is because Twig `set` is not able to manipulate arrays. This is only possible by using `merge` and then only on the top level of the array.

So first get the sub array where the key is placed and then merge the array key:

```
{% set item_content = item.content %}
{% set item_content = item_content|merge({'#view_mode': 'thumbnail'}) %}
{{ item_content }}
```

But I doubt that after you've solved the Twig issue this will work, because of how entities are rendered and cached. So you might have more success with [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak).

Comment: This solved the issue for me. But maybe because I'm altering twig and it still needs to be rendered in the next template.